# Mupad Greek symbols and text formatting in graphics

Tags: matlab, symbols

How I can use Greek symbols to name my 3d objects? How I can access to text formatting for the same purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the Mupad toolbox, but for core Matlab the documentation covers this issue very well.  Search online at the Mathworks site for 'latex' to learn how to put Greek (and other) letters into your graphics.

Comment: I use Mupad for nice 3d vector plotting